# Only the newest javafx button object works

Tags: java, javafx

Im trying to create a program that 'clones' itself, by making a new window and button etc. My issue is that only the newest created button functions. The previously made windows only generate an error, and not a window.

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.example.vboxes;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import static javafx.stage.StageStyle.DECORATED;

public class Controller
{
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    public HelloApplication hello = new HelloApplication();
    public VBox[] boxes = new VBox[99999];
    public Scene[] scenes = new Scene[99999];
    public Stage[] stages = new Stage[99999];
    public static int i = 0;
    @FXML
    private VBox box;
    @FXML
    public Button button;
    @FXML
    private Label text;
    @FXML
    protected void onClick() throws IOException
    {
        boxes[i] = new VBox();
        scenes[i] = new Scene(hello.loader.load(), 320, 240);
        stages[i] = new Stage(DECORATED);
        stages[i].setScene(scenes[i]);
        stages[i].setTitle("Dont click too many!");
        stages[i].show();
        double x = bounds.getMinX() + (bounds.getWidth() - scenes[i].getWidth());
        double y = bounds.getMinY() + (bounds.getHeight() - scenes[i].getHeight());
        stages[i].setX(rand.nextDouble(x));
        stages[i].setY(rand.nextDouble(y));
        System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

**HelloApplication.java**

```
package com.example.vboxes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{
    public FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml"));

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Don't exit!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();
    }
}
```

hello-view.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<VBox fx:id="box" alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.vboxes.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="text"/>
    <Button fx:id="buttons" text="Click me and more will appear!" onAction="#onClick"/>
</VBox>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>VBOXES</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>VBOXES</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
            <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.48</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.almasb</groupId>
            <artifactId>fxgl</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.vboxes/com.example.vboxes.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I attempted creating a button array that way each button functions, but I couldnt figure out how to link the button array to hello-view.fxml

Comment: Can you post your `HelloController`? (You posted the pom.xml instead.)

Comment: Or is the `Controller` class supposed to be the `HelloController` class?

Comment: Anyway, there is just a lot wrong with this code. Don't you get an exception if you try to press the same button twice? You would end up trying to use the same `FXMLLoader`, which you can't do because you can't reload when the root is already set. Why are you using arrays instead of lists when you don't know the number there are going to be? What is the purpose of the `boxes` array, which you don't ever use? (In fact, why do you think you need to keep track of all the scenes and windows at all? You can always access those from the relevant controller.)

Comment: Also, the arrays are not doing what you think they are. *Every* controller has its own copy of all the arrays, and if the button is pressed in the UI corresponding to that controller, then just one element of each array is initialized. It's really not clear at all what this code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the purpose of a lot of the code you wrote. If you just want the controller to be able to reload the same FXML, you can just do exactly that in the button handler.

The code you wrote fails if you try to use the same button twice. The reason is that each controller instance has a reference to one instance of the `HelloApplication` class, and via that reference accesses the `FXMLLoader` instance exposed by that object.

(As an aside, it's always wrong to instantiate the `Application` class.)

So if you press the same button twice, you attempt to call `load(...)` on the same `FXMLLoader` instance twice, and this won't work, at least with your setup, because the `FXMLLoader` can't load your FXML file when the root is already set (which it will be from the previous invocation of `load()`). (You could probably work around this by calling `setRoot(null)` on the loader, but the `FXMLLoader` is simply not designed to be used this way.)

Here's a working version of the `Application` class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Don't exit!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();
    }
}
```

And then all you need in the controller is

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import static javafx.stage.StageStyle.DECORATED;

public class HelloController
{
    private static final Random rand = new Random();

    // As things stand, you don't actually need any of the @FXML-annotated fields:
//    @FXML
//    private VBox box;
//    @FXML
//    private Button button;
//    @FXML
//    private Label text;

    @FXML
    protected void onClick() throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        int width = 320 ;
        int height = 240 ;
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), width, height);
        Stage stage = new Stage(DECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Dont click too many!");
        Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        double x = bounds.getMinX() + (bounds.getWidth() - width);
        double y = bounds.getMinY() + (bounds.getHeight() - height);
        stage.setX(rand.nextDouble(x));
        stage.setY(rand.nextDouble(y));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid hard-coding the location of the FXML a second time, you can inject it into the controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

import static javafx.stage.StageStyle.DECORATED;

public class HelloController
{
    private static final Random rand = new Random();

    @FXML
    private URL location;
    @FXML
    protected void onClick() throws IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(location);
        int width = 320 ;
        int height = 240 ;
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), width, height);
        Stage stage = new Stage(DECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Dont click too many!");
        Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        double x = bounds.getMinX() + (bounds.getWidth() - width);
        double y = bounds.getMinY() + (bounds.getHeight() - height);
        stage.setX(rand.nextDouble(x));
        stage.setY(rand.nextDouble(y));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I started programming in september, I still make beginner mistakes, sorry. Thank you for the help though! this solution works perfectly!